# How to dynamically create a method on a given class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I know that a method can be created with

```
class Klass
  define_method foo
```

How can you create a method and pass the class as a param?

```
def define_method_for klass, method
```

Ruby 2.2

Edit: Use case:

I am writing a mocking library. So, I want to mock arbitrary classes and methods.

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: What is the expected type of the second param `method` of `define_method_for `? A `Method`, a `Symbol` or a `String`?

Comment: @Aetherus - A symbol. What's a `Method`?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def define_method_for( klass, method, my_proc )
  klass.send( :define_method, method, my_proc )
end
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
class Klass
end

my_proc = proc { puts 'foo method called!' }
define_method_for( Klass, :foo, my_proc )

Klass.new.foo
#=> foo method called!
```

You could also define it like this:

```
 def define_method_for( klass, method, &block )
   klass.send( :define_method, method, &block )
 end
```

And use it like this:

```
 class Klass
 end

 define_method_for( Klass, :foo ) do
   puts 'foo method called!'
 end

 Klass.new.foo
 #=> foo method called!
```

Answer (score 2):

Either do:

```
klass.class_eval{define_method(:foo){...}}
```

or:

```
klass.instance_eval{define_method(:foo){...}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define it like this:

```
    dynamic_name = "ClassName"
    class = Object.const_set(dynamic_name, Class.new) 
    class.send(:define_method, 'method'){puts 'a'}
```

The wrapping into a method is straightforward.